# Does this OneWay Binding leak memory?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, memory-leaks, postsharp

I Am using a MVVM pattern in a WPF application and in educational purposes I have a question about Memory leaks.

I been using the Postsharp library.

My ViewModel looks like following:

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
     private ClassA _myClassAField; //ClassA doesn't Implement INotifyPropertyChanged

     public MyViewModel(ClassA classAParameter)
     {
          _myClassAField = classAParameter;
     }

     [NotifyPropertyChanged]
     public string Name { get { return _myClassAField.Name; } }


     .....//Other Code.....    
}
```

Xaml:

```
<Textblock Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

**Question:**

Does this binding leak memory?
In my testing it seems not to be leaking, but i do not understand why?

The binding to Property Name is only a getter from the ClassA that don't implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: Why do you think that there is a memory leak?

Comment: ClassA does not implement INotifyPropertyChanged. And my get property return The name of ClassA object. Or will the Name property marked with NotifyPropertyChanged override that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `ClassA` doesn't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` but you are binding to a property in the class `MyViewModel`, which does! Therefore you should not have memory leaks.

For reference: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/micmcd/2008/03/07/avoiding-a-wpf-memory-leak-with-databinding-black-magic/

> There is an issue where WPF checks to find things that implement
>   INotifyProperyChanged.  If there is a databinding to something not
>   implementing this interface, then it makes a record in a global table.
>   That record doesn’t get cleaned up, as WPF has no way of checking when
>   that DB record is no longer needed.

Comment: Ah I See! The Article you linked was really interesting and mind opening for me. I've just been exploring the memory leak area and want to have more knowledge about it.

Comment: @J.Olsson, Glad to help dude